# Obter QueryString e redirecionar com .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Gostaria de obter a a URL da querystring : url.htm e direcionar com htaccess.
Estou quase conseguindo:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)\.htm$ conteudo.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [qsappend]
RewriteRule ^conteudo.php(.*)$ http://meusite.com/nova-url-%1? [R=301,L]
```

Ex:

Pegar a URL

```
www.meusite.com/url.htm
```

e jogar para

```
www.meusite.com/nova-url-url.htm
```

Mas com esse `.htaccess` ele faz assim:

Resultado: `www.meusite.com/nova-url-`

Não retorna o `url.htm`

Só isso preciso para finalizar.

Comment: a flag `[qsappend]` indica *query string append* então você não precisa adicionar `&%{QUERY_STRING}` na regra *RewriteRule*.

Comment: poderia explicar onde o arquivo `conteudo.php` entra na sua regra? ele está no .htaccess mas você não descreveu o que ele deve fazer. Aparentemente ele é só faz a ligação entra as duas *RewriteRule*

Answer (score 1):

a substituição está errada em:

```
RewriteRule ^conteudo.php(.*)$ http://meusite.com/nova-url-%1? [R=301,L]
```

O `%1?` deveria ser `$1`

Comment: Infelizmente também não da certo.
Ele não retorna nada no fim da URL