# Redirecionar site com .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

Boa Tarde!

Quero fazer um redirecionamento em meu site e não estou encontrando a solução.

Quero que quando o cara acesse pelo ip por exemplo: https://1.2.3.4 ele direcione para https://nome_do_site

É possível com .htaccess?

Lembrando que é somente interno.

Obrigado

Comment: Possível Duplicata --> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64878/obter-querystring-e-redirecionar-com-htaccess

Comment: Não é, ali fala sobre nome->nome eu preciso de ip->nome

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 127\.0\.0\.1
    RewriteRule $ /outrapagina.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Ref.: http://www.netshinesoftware.com/blog/restricting-access-to-a-url-by-ip-address-using-mod-rewrite/